# Objective C - How can i get the weekday from NSDate?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, weekday

I need to be able to get the weekday from nsdate, i have the following code and it always return 1. I tried to change the month, i tried everything from 1 to 12 but the result of the week day is always 1.

```
NSDate *date2 = [[NSDate alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d-%d", 2010, 6, 1]];
unsigned units2 = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
NSCalendar *calendar2 = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components2 = [calendar2 components:units2 fromDate:date2];
int startWeekDay = [components2 weekday];
[date2 release];
[calendar2 release];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the day of the week with Cocoa Touch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269093/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-the-week-with-cocoa-touch)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit for Mac:**

The format of the string has to be *—YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS ±HHMM* according to the docs, all fields mandatory

**Old answer (for iPhone and tested on simulator):**

There is no (public) `-initWithString:` method in `NSDate`, and what you get returned is *not* what you expect.

Use a properly configured (you need to give the input format) `NSDateFormatter` and `-dateFromString:`.

Comment: yes there is > – initWithString: and my problem was the format of my string

Answer (score 43):

Creating an `NSDateFormatter` that only contains the weekday will do what you want.

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *weekday = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[weekday setDateFormat: @"EEEE"];
NSLog(@"The day of the week is: %@", [weekday stringFromDate:now]);
```

If you need internationalization, the `NSDateFormatter` can be sent a locale, which will give the proper translation.

The date formatters are controlled through this standard: [Unicode Date Formats](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: I think the OP wants an integer of the day of the week (for example, 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday, 3 = Wednesday, etc).

Comment: If you want the integer you just a set: [weekday setDateFormat: @"e"]; You also should set NSLocale... eg:      NSLocale *deLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"de_DE"] autorelease];   [weekday setLocale:deLocale]; Otherwise Thursday might be 5 instead of 4, if the starting day of the week is Sunday or Monday..

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, The problem was that the format of my date string was wrong:

```
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d-%d 10:45:32 +0600", selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay]];
```

and since i don't care about the time i randomly pass a time to the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Xcode 6.4

There are many ways to setup an NSDate.  I won't go over that here.  You've done it one way, using a string (A method I avoid due to it being very vulnerable to error), and I'm setting it another way.  Regardless, access your components weekday or setDay methods.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
[calendar setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-US"]];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitWeekday|NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

this way, you can get or set any of these components like this:

```
[components weekday] //to get, then doSomething
[components setDay:6]; //to set
```

and, of course, set `NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];`only after you've changed the components.

I added in the extra local and other components for context in case you'd like to set those too.

It's free code, don't knock it.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone coming here looking for a more recent Swift 4 solution:

```
extension Date {

    func getDayOfWeek() -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
        dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("EEEE")

        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

`let inputString = "2018-04-16T15:47:39.000Z"`

`let result = inputString.getDayOfWeek()`

result = `Monday`

Answer (score 0):

Most upvoting answer in Swift 3.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
print("The day of the week is \(formatter.string(from: Date()))")
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following website which helped with setting up the string to retrieve the format I wanted on my date

[Coder Wall - Guide to objective c date formatting](https://coderwall.com/p/jj6k_a/quick-guide-to-objective-c-dateformatting)