# Not able to get the day of the week to display

Tags: ios, xcode, date, nsdate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the day of the week in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269093/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-the-week-in-objective-c)

I have a uilabel that is connected to a nsstring. However, I am trying to set the nsstring to the day of the week (monday, tuesday, etc.). Every time I run it though, it gives me nothing. I have a feeling though that it is because I am not getting a value from my nsdate. However, I'm new to xcode, so I don't really know understand what I've done wrong.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
     NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                                 initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

        // Get the weekday component of the current date
        NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit
                                                           fromDate:today];

       NSString *dateString = weekdayComponents;
        _label.text = dateString;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code instead:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
    _label.text = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A primary issue is that you are attempting to assign an `NSDateComponents` object to an `NSString` variable.

The answer given by @JShapiro is a good one. But if you want to use `NSDateComponents` you could do this:

```
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger weekday = [weekdayComponents weekday];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSArray *weekdayNames = [formatter weekdaySymbols];

_label.text = weekdayNames[weekday];
```