# NSCalendar, why does setting the firstWeekday doesn't effect calculation outcome?

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsdate, nscalendar

i need to calculate the weekday for a given date, however, depending on the calendar a week can star on Monday and somwhere on Sunday

so i wanted to set it, to start on Monday, using

```
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] setFirstWeekday:2];
```

however, the calculation outcome is the same

```
{
    [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] setFirstWeekday:1];
    NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
    NSInteger weekday = [weekdayComponents weekday] - 1;
    NSLog(@"%d", weekday);
}
{
    [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] setFirstWeekday:2];
    NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
    NSInteger weekday = [weekdayComponents weekday] - 1;
    NSLog(@"%d", weekday);
}
```

returns same numbers, but why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The behavior you see is correct. The weekday component is not affected by the firstWeekday property. If you have a date representing a sunday it will always be a sunday wether you start your week on that sunday or on monday. What this should affect is the week number in the week property of your date components.

Comment: so Sunday will always be weekday 0, no matter what the firstWeekday points?

Comment: Sunday 1, Monday 2, Tuesday 3, Wednesday 4, Friday 5, Saturday 6

Comment: @Peter Lapisu dont forget Thur! :-)

Comment: In details, NSCalendar's `firstWeekDay` just influences `NSDateComponents`'s `weekOfMonth/weekOfYear/yearForWeekOfYear` property. By the way, NSCalendar's `week` property is deprecated, and substituted by `weekOfMonth` and `weekOfYear`.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you need to use the `ordinalityOfUnit:inUnit:forDate:` method rather than attempting to extract the date components. So something like this:

```
NSUInteger weekday = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] ordinalityOfUnit:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit forDate:date];
```

Basically that call is asking for the day (`NSWeekdayCalendarUnit`) in the week (`NSWeekCalendarUnit`) for the given date.

If that doesn't work as is, you may need to create your own calendar, rather than trying to modifying the first week day on the `currentCalendar`.

For example:

```
NSCalendarIdentifier calendarIdentifier = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] calendarIdentifier];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:calendarIdentifier] autorelease];
[calendar setFirstWeekday:2];
```

Then use that new `calendar` object rather than `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]` in the `ordinalityOfUnit:inUnit:forDate:` call.

Comment: NSWeekCalendarUnit is deprecated :/

Comment: Perhaps try one of the other week units: `NSWeekOfMonthCalendarUnit` or `NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit`. They don't really make sense in this context, but it's worth trying.

Comment: If you're finding you're getting strange values when simply plugging in `NSWeekOfMonthCalendarUnit` or `NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit`, try...


`NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]];`

Answer (score 0):

A useful function to get corrected weekday number for different firstWeekday cases

**Swift 3.0**

```
func dayOfWeek(day: Int, month: Int, year: Int) -> Int {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let dateComponents = DateComponents(year: year, month: month, day: day)

    guard let date = calendar.date(from: dateComponents) else {
        fatalError("Can't create date form specified date components")
    }

    var weekday = calendar.component(.weekday, from: date)

    //handling the case when calendar starts from Monday: firstWeekday == 2
    if calendar.firstWeekday == 2 {
        weekday = (weekday == 1) ? 7 : (weekday - 1)
    }

    return weekday
}
```