# How do I know what day a given date is?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nscalendar

For example, given a date 13/09/2013(it is Saturday), how can I know what day it is in code?
are there some methods in NSCalendar or NSdate can calculate this for me?

Comment: Don't know if this is the proper one, if you use NSDateFormatter, with format EEEE you can get the day of the date.

Comment: BTW: 13-Sep-2013 is a Friday

Comment: @JamesWebster maybe it's Saturday in *some* calendar ;)

Comment: I added Sep instead of 9 to counter that :P I'm fairly confident other calendars will have a ninth month, but I doubt they have a "September" =]

Comment: [Julian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar) has September :)

Comment: Phew! 13-Sep-2013 Julian was a Thursday =]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a DateFormatter to get the day of the week for a specific date as a string.  You can also use NSDateComponents to get an integer value that represents the day of week.

See this SO post and answers...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4269211

Answer (score 1):

You can also (but I'm not sure if it's better in any way) get the weekday component and names from the calendar.

```
NSDate *yourDate     = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponent = 
    [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit
                                    fromDate:yourDate];

NSString *dayName = calendar.weekdaySymbols[weekdayComponent.weekday-1];

NSLog(@"today is %@", dayName); // Output: today is Thursday
```