# Getting the current day of the week in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get the current day of the week in order to change an image based on what day it is. I am getting an error with my current code: "Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type." I'm pretty new to swift and ios, so I'm not quite sure what to change.

```
   func getDayOfWeek()->Int? {
    if let todayDate = NSDate() {
        let myCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)
        let myComponents = myCalendar?.components(.WeekdayCalendarUnit, fromDate: todayDate)
        let weekDay = myComponents?.weekday
        return weekDay
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533147/get-day-of-week-using-nsdate-swift

Answer (score 8):

Your error message is due to the fact that in the line

`if let todayDate = NSDate()`

the `if let ...` has a special meaning in swift. The compiler tries to bind a optional variable to a constant. As `NSDate()` doesn't return an optional value, this is an error.

Leave off the `if` and it should work:

```
func getDayOfWeek()->Int? {
   let todayDate = NSDate()
   let myCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)   
   let myComponents = myCalendar?.components(.WeekdayCalendarUnit, fromDate: todayDate)
   let weekDay = myComponents?.weekday
   return weekDay
 }
```