# How to get the difference of weekdays?

Tags: ios, swift, date

I have this information:

```
Days  Dec'15  Jan'16
---------------------
Sun    27
Mon    28
Tue    29
Wed    30
Thu    31
Fri             1
Sat             2
```

I have `1st Jan'16`. So I have to get `Fri` and then the difference of days from the `Sun`. So, in this case, the difference should be 5. Because, before Friday there are 5 other days. So if I want to know it for `2nd Jan'16` it should be 6. And likewise.

How do I get it easy with date functions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get day of week using NSDate swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533147/get-day-of-week-using-nsdate-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code may help you

```
extension Date {

    func weekdayDiffence() -> Int {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([Calendar.Component.weekday], from: self).weekday ?? 0

    }
}
```

**Example**

```
let d = Date().weekdayDiffence()
print(d)
```