# UITableviews inside UICollectionViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to make a calendar like a google calendar in which each square has some text (events of the day).

For this, I think I must put a `UITableView` inside each `UICollectionViewCell`, but I am not accomplishing it. I don’t have a sample code because I don’t even know how to start solving this.

Comment: May [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52045681/custom-cell-with-uitableview-inside-uicollectionviewcell) SO question could help you.

Answer (score 1):

We don't need a `UITableView`, we can do it just by using `UICollectionView`.

**But as you are new** to this I suggest using a library `JTAppleCalender`.

With this library, you can create a calendar in iOS very easily and it is highly customizable.

List of features:

- Range selection - select dates in a range. The design is entirely up
  to you.
- Boundary dates - limit the calendar date range
- Week/month mode - show 1 row of weekdays. Or 2, 3 or 6
- Custom cells - make your day-cells look however you want, with any
  functionality you want
- Custom calendar view - make your calendar look however you want, with
  what ever functionality you want
- First Day of week - pick anyday to be first day of the week
- Horizontal or vertical mode
- Ability to add month headers in varying sizes/styles of your liking
- Ability to scroll to any month by simply using the date
- Ability to design your calendar however you want. You want it, you
  build it.

Github link: https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar

**If you think that you don't want to use any library this answer may help you**: [Custom calender View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49751354/custom-calender-view)

Comment: I am sorry, but what is a library?

Comment: Please follow this link to add this library using cocoapods: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html

Comment: Library is a framework which helps you perform some complicated task easily as they provide lots of prebuilt functionality

Comment: Is there another way to do it (my first approach for example). Because I don’t want to install anything in my computer.

Comment: Yes you can but it will be more complex for as you are beginner. See the last link in the answer.