# How to create two variables with the current time and day of the week?

Tags: swift, swift3

I want to create two variables - one with today's day of the week (Monday - Sunday) and one with the current time. I want to do more than just display it in a label, but am just trying that for now.

I tried this, but my app crashes:

```
let weekDay = NSCalendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date())
self.weekDayLabel.text = "\(weekDay)"
```

Comment: What's the error? Which line crashes?

Comment: And don't use `NSCalendar`, use `Calendar`.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't know :( and ok! But it still crashes and I'm not sure why

Comment: Make sure `weekDayLabel` outlet is connected to Storyboard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get day of week using NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533147/get-day-of-week-using-nsdate)

Answer (score 0):

```
let date = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"

let dayInWeek = formatter.string(from: date)
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answers. Include some context; an explanation of what you changed or why you wrote it in the way you did or detailing the original cause of the problem so that the OP and others with the same problem can get an understanding of the code you've written and what it changes.