# How can I design a string type extension that represents a day of the week and returns the corresponding number? On Swift

Tags: swift, extension-methods

I need to design a String type extension that represents a day of the week and returns the corresponding number starting with Sunday = 1 and ending with Saturday = 7

for example sunday = 1 , monday = 2 , tuesday = 3 , wednesday = 4 ,thurday = 5 , friday = 6, saturday = 7

Here is one idea that i have, but i don't know how to put the Int for the value of the day of the week:

```
extension String{
   var sunday: String {return self}
   var monday: String {return self}
   var tuesday:String {return self}
   var wednesday: String {return self}
   var thursday: String {return self}
   var friday: String {return self}
   var saturday: String {return self}
}
```

Another idea is this but i don't know how to return the number or if its value to add the days of the week below to daysW :

```
extension String{
   var daysW:String{
       return self
   }
   func number() -> Int{
   return self
   }
}
.daysW
.number()
```

Please can somebody help me , i'm new with Swift and it's confusing

Comment: I may be missing why you want an extension. Normally I would think you'd want a dictionary. e.g. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_dictionaries.htm.  Allows you to create key value pairs.  Also, the built in Calendar/date handling allows you to get days of week by number. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533147/get-day-of-week-using-nsdate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You better create a enumeration where its rawValue is a string and add a computed property to return a value:

```
extension Calendar {
    enum Weekday: String, CaseIterable, CustomStringConvertible {
        case sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday
        var description: String { rawValue.capitalized }
        var value: Int { Self.allCases.firstIndex(where: {$0.rawValue == rawValue})! + 1 }
    }
}
```

---

```
let monday = Calendar.Weekday.monday
print(monday)        // Monday
print(monday.value)  // 2
```

If you need to convert the string to a number you can initialize a new case and return its value:

```
extension String {
    var weekday: Int? { Calendar.Weekday(rawValue: lowercased())?.value }
}
```

---

```
"monday".weekday  // 2
"Monday".weekday  // 2
"MONDAY".weekday  // 2
```

Comment: In the section of {$0.rawValue == rawValue} it gives me an error that says: instance member "rawValue" cannot be used on type "Calendar.Weekday. I do not know if it is due to the fact of not having a physical mac, I use a license to access a remote mac

Comment: @AskBee are you sure you have the exact code as above?

Comment: Note that you can only access the rawValue property on your enumeration cases  `Calendar.Weekday.monday.rawValue` // "Monday" or value `Calendar.Weekday.monday.value` // 2

Comment: I see my mistake, sorry it's just that swift suggested me to make changes and I think that affected. An apology

Comment: The caseiterable helps us determine how many cases we have and in a way lists them when they do not have a value? Could you explain to me what the CustumStringConvertible and the capitalized does? please

Comment: [CaseIterable protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/caseiterable) means you can convert the values to a collection (array) accessing `allValues` properties `CustumStringConvertible` allows you to print the cases as well do string interpolation with them. Capitalized allows you to display them starting with an Uppercase letter.

Comment: And when we define the 'enum', the value is assigned to each case and the 'rawValue' saves the implicit values ​​for each case?

Comment: `rawValue` is the actual value of the enumeration cases. If you define its type as `String`
 it will (by default) have the same value as its name. You can also define a different value to each case `case sunday, monday = "Monday", tuesday ...` which I didn't (I only changed the way it prints).

Comment: and first of all thank you very much, I really learned a lot with your help. Totally grateful to you