# NSDate get all short days of the week?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I need to get all days of the week in their short mode, like this:

```
sun,mon,etc ..
```

I have tried this:

```
NSDateFormatter * df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]]];
[df setDateFormat:@"c"];
```

Which always gives the full names, how would you get the short ones?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSArray * shortWeeks = [formatter shortWeekdaySymbols];
NSLog(@"%@",shortWeeks);
```

Log

```
   2015-07-14 17:25:31.470 NewOcTest[9016:286325] (
Sun,
Mon,
Tue,
Wed,
Thu,
Fri,
Sat
)
```

Also,there is also `veryShortWeekdaySymbols` in `dateFormatter`

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSArray * shortWeeks = [formatter veryShortWeekdaySymbols];
NSLog(@"%@",shortWeeks);
```

Log

```
2015-07-14 17:30:30.686 NewOcTest[9073:290513] (
S,
M,
T,
W,
T,
F,
S
)
```

Comment: Is there a way to get this based on region? Ex. in Europe first day of week is Monday.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `ccc`

```
[df setDateFormat:@"ccc"];
```

> Stand-Alone local day of week - Use one letter for the local numeric value (same as 'e'), three for the short day, four for the full name, five for the narrow name, or six for the short name.

See the [unicode docs](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Alternatively use `eee` or `E` - not sure what exactly the differences are.

> Day of week - Use one through three letters for the short day, or four for the full name, five for the narrow name, or six for the short name.

or

> Local day of week. Same as E except adds a numeric value that will depend on the local starting day of the week, using one or two letters. For this example, Monday is the first day of the week.

Comment: thanks but it still not working in my configuration (changing the c to ccc would still gives full names)

Comment: @Curnelious what about the `eee` or `E`?

Comment: he wants days of the week AFAICS.. not the week's calendar number

Comment: @Daij-Djan okay, I see, I apparently misunderstood the question :/

Answer (score 1):

Day of the week in a short 3-char style like 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', ...

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE"];
NSString *strDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

**OR** (for your code)

```
NSDateFormatter * df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]]];
[df setDateFormat:@"EEE"];
```

Answer (score 1):

use shortWeekdaySymbols, it gives an array of the names

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSDateFormatter * df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"%@ \n OR \n %@", df.weekdaySymbols, df. df.shortWeekdaySymbols);
    }
}
```

no need to use any formatting except if you are in fact not looking for the week but for a single date:
[How do I get the day of the week with Cocoa Touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269093/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-the-week-in-objective-c)