# How to get Day number of week from NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to know the day number of week from NSDate.

Example:- Suppose today is 10th Oct 2016, Here Week number is 3rd which i got using

```
NSInteger week = [_calendar component:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth fromDate:date];
```

Now I want to know the day number of current week, Which is 2nd for 10th Oct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the day of the week with Cocoa Touch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269093/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-the-week-with-cocoa-touch)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will fetch you the day number **i.e. 2**. The day number are always same for every week. (1-7).

As pointed by **Vyachaslav Gerchicov**, the weekday number starts from Sunday
**i.e** Sunday is 1, Monday is 2... Saturday is 7

```
//Assuming your calendar is initiated like this
NSCalendar *_calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

//Fetch the day number
NSInteger day = [_calendar component:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:date];
```

Explore `NSCalendar` for more details [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscalendarunit/)

**For Swift 5.x**

```
let day = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: date)
```

Explore `Calendar` for more details [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar)

Comment: if i have a day of the year say 111th day how can i retrieve it as 21-04-2018

Comment: You forgot to mention that Sunday is 1.

Comment: @XcodianSolangi I am very late to the party. But if you want to do something like retrieving the date from day number. Just take the date as 1 Jan 2018 and add 111 days. This will yield you a new Date. Explore the Calendar.current.date(byAdding...) method. Here is the link in case you are interested.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5067868/2545465

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekday ) fromDate:[NSDate date] ];
NSNumber *weekNo = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:dateComponent. weekday];
```

Comment: It is giving a day number?. I guess it should give the yearly week number

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari it's return year week no.

Comment: Read the question again then

Comment: Did you even try to print the value of your variable `weekNo`. Just print it once and see the problem. I suppose it will give you the max int value and not the desired result

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari plz chek it now.