# how do I get the day of the week using NSDate and show using NSLog in iOS?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective C - How can i get the weekday from NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524363/objective-c-how-can-i-get-the-weekday-from-nsdate)

How do I get the day of the week using NSDate and show using NSLog?

I wonder the current day, such as today.

Ex: NSLog(@"the day is:",day)
Resp: "the day is: Monday"

Answer (score 23):

```
NSDateFormatter* day = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[day setDateFormat: @"EEEE"];
NSLog(@"the day is: %@", [day stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Comment: Hi,

  
how do I put this value in a variable?    
I want to use an if, for example: if (day == "monday") {...}

Comment: NSString* dayString = [day stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

Answer (score 16):

Using NSDateComponents:

```
static inline NSString *stringFromWeekday(int weekday)
{
    static NSString *strings[] = {
        @"Sunday",
        @"Monday",
        @"Tuesday", 
        @"Wednesday",
        @"Thursday",
        @"Friday",
        @"Saturday",
    };

    return strings[weekday - 1];
}


NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSLog(@"%@", stringFromWeekday([components weekday]));
```

Of course, this doesn't respect locales & such.

Comment: Don't hardcode the weekday names. You can get them from `NSDateFormatter weekdaySymbols`.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"the day is: %@", [[NSDate date] descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%A" timeZone:nil locale:nil]);
```

Comment: Doesn't work with iOS 9 and above