# How can I set the day of the week as a variable in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making a basic iOS app and I need to return just the current day of the week as a string variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you need the name of the current weekday in the current locale:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
let today = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let todayComponents = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitWeekday, fromDate: today)
let weekDayIdx = todayComponents.weekday
let weekday = dateFormatter.weekdaySymbols[weekDayIdx] as! String
println(weekday) // "Wednesday"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go buddy:

```
    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: date)
    let hour = components.hour
    let minutes = components.minute
    let month = components.month
    let year = components.year
    let day = components.day
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

This is not a "write my code for me" site. It's a site for help with specific problems with your code that you have written.

I'll give you some suggestions:

The easiest way to do this is probably with an NSDateFormatter. Take a look at this thread (specifically the answer by Jon Shier)

[Objective C - How can i get the weekday from NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524363/objective-c-how-can-i-get-the-weekday-from-nsdate)

It looks like you want an NSDateFormatter with the format string "EEEE":

```
let now = NSDate()
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
let weekday = formatter.stringFromDate(now)
```